# Spring @EnableWebMvc configuration using DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I started to move away from my XML based configuration to a @EnableWebMvc and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter one. But when I changed the configuration it seems like it switched from the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping to the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.

If I want to switch back to the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping how do I actually set that up?

(I know that DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is deprecated but I still want to know how I setup spring to use it)

Comment: What was your original XML config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [javadoc of `@EnableWebMvc`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) states

> Adding this annotation to an `@Configuration` class imports the Spring
>   MVC configuration from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` [...]

where [`WebMvcConfigurationSupport`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html)

> This class registers the following `HandlerMappings`:
>
> - `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` ordered at 0 for mapping requests to annotated controller methods.
> - `HandlerMapping` ordered at 1 to map URL paths directly to view names.
> - `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` ordered at 2 to map URL paths to controller bean names.
> - `HandlerMapping` ordered at `Integer.MAX_VALUE-1` to serve static resource requests.
> - `HandlerMapping` ordered at `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to forward requests to the default servlet.

That's where the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` comes from. This "default" configuration is more or less equivalent to specifying

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in an XML configuration.

If you want to declare a `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` ahead (in order) of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, then declare your own bean for it and set its order lower.

```
@Bean
public DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping() {
    DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
    defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
    // and other properties
    return defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping;
}
```

If you want this to be the only `HandlerMapping` registered in the `DispatcherServlet`, then name the bean `"handlerMapping"` and set the [`DispatcherServlet#detectAllHandlerMappings`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#setDetectAllHandlerMappings-boolean-) property to `false`.